# Sequence of function calls (C++)

Tags: c++, function, sequence

```
result= function_1()*function_2();
```

I am writing a code like above. What I want to know is while doing the multiplication, which function is called first? That is because, the first called function can effect the result returned from the other function. I assumed `function_1()` is called first, and when I tried I saw that it is really so. However, is it always the case? Does it depend on which compiler I use or the system I work on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Order of evaluation is unspecified by the C++ (or the C) standard (see [answer from Vlad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26626938/841108)). If your `function_1` or `function_2` have significant [side-effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29), it may become some [*unspecified* behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior) which you should absolutely avoid (like you should avoid [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)). And in some cases (inlined functions with strong optimizations) the computations might be intermixed.

Think about weird cases like

```
 static int i;
 int function_1(void) { i++; return i; }
 int function_2(void) { i+=2; return 3*i+1; }
```

It probably is implementation specific, and might depend upon the actual compiler and the [optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) flags.

You should code as if the order of function calls is completely random and not reproducible (even if *in practice* it might be reproducible). Likewise, you should not expect any particular order of arguments evaluation (e.g. in `f(i++, ++j)` you don't know if `i` or `j` has been incremented first), even if for a given compiler that order might be fixed. Again, you should imagine a completely random and non-reproducible order.

As commented by [David Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721269/david-schwartz), if you care about the order, you should code explicitly some [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point)

At last, if your code is depending upon some order, it is completely unreadable and for that simple readability reason you should avoid coding this way.

Comment: If you care, you need to insert a sequence point between the function calls. Like `result=function_1(); result*=function_2();`.

Comment: This cannot cause undefined behaviour (unless `function_1` or `function_2` are macros). There is a sequence point before and after a function body.

Comment: If `function_1` and `function_2` are inlined, I believe the compiler might optimize to mix both codes...

Comment: It still can't cause UB, the compiler has to obey the as-if rule

Comment: Thanks about UB. Improved my answer!

Comment: "This is unspecified" is too vague. It sounds like the C++ standard doesn't say anything about this. But it does. It specifies that the evaluation order is unspecified. So a more precise statement would be that "the order of evaluation of subexpressions is unspecified".

Comment: I think multiplication yields same result in either case (left evaluated first, or right evaluated first). This concern can be checked by putting break points in each function and test , the complier used will follow what sequence.

Comment: Not with `static int i; int function_1(void) {i+=1; return i;}; int function_2(void) {i+=2; return i;}`

Answer (score 4):

According to the C++ Standard (1.9 Program execution)

> 15 Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators
>   and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced.

So in this expression

```
result= function_1()*function_2();
```

some compilers can evaluate at first function_1() and then function_2() while other compilers can evaluate at first function_2() and only then function_1(). Even if you write like

```
result= (function_1())*(function_2());
```

or

```
result= (function_1())*function_2();
```

or

```
result= function_1()*(function_2());
```

nothing will be changed relative to the order of evaluation of the operands.